# How to retrieve a PDF file from an iOS device?

Tags: ios, itunes, books

Given two Macs running Yosemite and one iPad running iOS 8, how do you retrieve a PDF file put on the iPad from Mac 1, using Mac 2 ? Let's say that I don't currently have access to the Mac used to put the file in the first place. I can see the file in the Books section of the device in iTunes, but that's all I can do right now.

Comment: You should be able to drag it out of iTunes to the desktop

Comment: Yes. *should*. But iTunes won't let it go.

Comment: hmmm - might be because it's not 'native' to that machine. Never tried it on other than my main Mac. Maybe see how you get on with something like iFunBox - review & link - http://lifehacker.com/5914638/the-best-desktop-file-explorer-for-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Try emailing it to yourself from the iPad.

Comment: While it's technically working, I'm looking for a way to do this without network connection, and a third party service.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using Air Drop? I've used it several times for sending in retrieving items.

Comment: iBooks does not have a Share with Airdrop option, unfortunately.